# How to show many options vs. just one in a menu situation

Tags: menu

Can anyone help answer this question?

[image]

[image]

I have a dilemma, in some pages I have only one option, while in other pages I have maybe 2 or more. Should I be consistent and show a menu drop down all the time, or be contextually sensitive, and show just the option when there is only one, and show the menu when the screen has two or more?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do these actions fall in your interface? Are these row actions for a data grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the pages where you have only one option, show that option as a stand alone not inside a dropdown. If you add a single option inside a dropdown you are making your user waste a click for no reason at all.

> Don't waste your user's time and attention on searching on your page
>   for the options he needs.

On those pages where you have only two options, you can also consider showing them as individual buttons if the space on the page allows this [options like **add**, **delete** or **edit**]

For more options you can show them inside a dropdown.

Comment: Thank you, Alin. Appreciate your reasoning on this. That's was my thought process as well.

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion, drop downs are primarily useful when multiple choices are necessary/mandatory **to do something/get somewhere**.  If some screen needs just one or two options displayed stay straight and go standalone.

> **Keep it simple, be direct.**

Agreed 100% with Alin.